# HQL implicit join in where clause generate cross join instead of inner join

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm using Hibernate 3.6 and MSSQL 2012.

When executing this HQL

```
select tbl.state from Property tbl where tbl.state = 1 and tbl.entity.state = 1 and
tbl.entity.className = 'com....' and tbl.fieldName = 'fieldName'
```

I'm getting this SQL

```
select property0_.State as col_0_0_ from Properties property0_ cross join Entities
entity1_ where property0_.refEntityid=entity1_.id and property0_.State=1 and
entity1_.State=1 and entity1_.ClassName='com....' and property0_.FieldName='fieldName'
```

*Notice the **cross join** and the **added condition** in the where clause.

According to Hibernate docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms

implicit join should generate to **inner join**.

I've noticed that there is an open bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7707 that may be referring to this problem but no one answered and it's opened for a year already.

I would appreciate any information about this issue. Thank you.

PS. I'm well aware that using implicit joins is not the right way of writing HQL but I can't do anything about this right now.

Comment: Wow, this is really really lame and broken on the part of hibernate. `where foo.bar is not null or foo.bar.baz = x` returns a completely illogical zero results if all foo objects have a null bar reference...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your join is an inner join, but using the old syntax consisting in adding a condition in the where clause:

```
where property0_.refEntityid=entity1_.id
```

instead of doing it with

```
inner join Entities entity1_ on property0_.refEntityid=entity1_.id
```

The result is exactly the same.

And using implicit joins in HQL is not a problem at all, as long as you understand what they're doing.

Comment: Everything you said is fine but It doesn't explain why I'm getting cross join + added where condition instead of normal inner join like the docs say.

Comment: After reading your answer I went back to the "Forms of join syntax" section in the hibernate docs and re-read it couple of times. Now I am starting to realize that the term "inner join" used there, does not necessary means to the inner join syntax but just for the inner join action that may be done in two ways, proper inner join or cross join with added where clause. So now, I can get back to eating, sleeping and bathing and let it GO. Thank you @jb-nizet

Comment: For information, I had a triple cross join with added where clause, after checking the EXPLAIN, I can confirm i get the exact same plan of execution. I panicked a bit when I saw some other posts talking about that those generated cross join by hibernate were bad and were changing their criteria request... for nothing in fact, luckily I ended here :-)

Answer (score 3):

When using HQL, always use proper aliases when performing join operations.Your query should be something like that:

```
select tbl.state 
from Property tbl 
left join tbl.entity entity 
where tbl.state = 1 
    and entity.state = 1 
    and entity.className = 'com....' 
    and tbl.fieldName = 'fieldName'
```

Otherwise if you try to use `tbl.entity.someProperty`, in HQL, it will always create a crossJoin