# Hibernate cross join and not inner join

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

I have two entities (Order, Account) and use the following relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
}
```

I want to get all orders by Account name.
I am using JPA repository and all I need is to define method with specific name:

```
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, String> {
    List<Order> findByAccountName(String accountName);
}
```

Hibernate generates the following sql query:

```
select order0_.id as id1_1_, order0_.account_id as account20_1_ from orders order0_ cross join accounts account1_ where order0_.account_id=account1_.id and account1_.name = ?
```

I understand that having `order0_.account_id=account1_.id` condition cross join has the same behavior as inner join, but my question is: 
Why hibernate does not use inner join? 
It looks for me that I missed something in config.

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HQL implicit join in where clause generate cross join instead of inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240959/hql-implicit-join-in-where-clause-generate-cross-join-instead-of-inner-join)

Comment: Also, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7707 (mentioned in the above post), especially [this comment](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7707?focusedCommentId=73133&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-73133) - ie. "the result is the same, why do you care?"