# Hibernate selecting list with condition (true or something causes NPE) returns no results

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity called 'OrganizationVideo' that has one-to-one entity called 'Video' that has parent entity called 'OrganizationIssue' that has boolean field called `published`

A query is built to select any `OrganizationVideo` that has `video having OrganizationIssue.published=true` OR doesn't have any `OrganziationIssues` `organizationIssue is null`

```
select ov from OrganizationVideo ov where (ov.video.organizationIssue is null OR  ov.video.organizationIssue.published=true)
```

So question is why this query returns nothing when second OR doesn't match that means that `ov.video.organizationIssue is null`

If hibernate works as Java that could be valid since second operand will fire `NullPointerException`

Generated SQL statment :

```
select organizati0_.id as organizati0_.organization from organization_video organizati0_ left outer join video video1_ on organizati0_.id=video1_.id cross join organization_issue organizati2_ where video1_.organization_issue=organizati2_.id and organizati0_.organization=? and (video1_.organization_issue is null or organizati2_.published=1) order by organizati0_.id desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refer to `ov.video` in multiple places you need to do an explicit JOIN so then it uses this join for both parts of the WHERE (rather than doing a separate INNER JOIN for each). You likely would have worked this out by looking at the SQL generated from your query.

Using explicit joins you get more like

```
SELECT ov FROM OrganizationVideo ov LEFT OUTER JOIN ov.video v LEFT OUTER JOIN v.organisationIssues oi
WHERE (oi is null OR oi.published=true)
```

You could use (INNER) JOIN there depending on the precise requirement, but the point is the same ... by explicitly specifying joins you guarantee what happens.

Comment: That is good as query optimization but not a solution to my problem

Comment: "It doesn't work". so what does your DEBUGGING tell you? you know, look at the SQL invoked?

Comment: No results : the query actually returns 0 results I updated the question with SQL statement genearted

Comment: This is the SQL generated for this query , I found a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/20240959/1460591

Comment: For WHAT query???? You have a query. I suggested a DIFFERENT query. Decide what you are asking and repose the question

Comment: Sorry the generated SQL for your query not the original one in the question :

Comment: Exception : QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join

Comment: Thank you , It is now working I edited the joining path . Finally query doesn't generate any cross joins and worked as expected, Thanks again :)