# Spring JPA slow query with Oracle using like and upper

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, oracle19c

I encounter an optimisation problem and I can't figure out why my query is so slow.

In production when searching for `document.name` the application takes about 4 minutes when there are no results and without `IDX_DOC_NAME_UPPER`. With `IDX_DOC_NAME_UPPER` it is variable from 40s to 2m.
In **sqlplus** it takes about 3-4s with index and without 8-9s.

`DOCUMENTS` contains about 2M records and `ACTIVITIES` 7M records.

### DB SCHEMA

```sql
-- DOCUMENTS
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENTS
(
    ID          NUMBER(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME        VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    DOC_SIZE    NUMBER(16)    NOT NULL,
    CREATED     TIMESTAMP     NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_DOC_NAME_UPPER ON DOCUMENTS (UPPER(NAME));

-- USERS
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    ID    NUMBER(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    CNAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    --others, removed for brevity
);

-- ACTIVITIES
CREATE TABLE ACTIVITIES
(
    ID     NUMBER(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    USR_ID NUMBER(16) references USERS (ID) NOT NULL,
    DOC_ID NUMBER(16) references DOCUMENTS (ID),
    PRT_ID NUMBER(16) references USERS (ID) NOT NULL
    --others, removed for brevity
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_ACT_USR_ID ON ACTIVITIES (USR_ID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_ACT_DOC_ID ON ACTIVITIES (DOC_ID);

-- LOGS
CREATE VIEW V_LOGS AS
SELECT CNAME,
       ACTIVITIES.USR_ID,
       PRT_ID,
       DOC_ID
       --others, removed for brevity
FROM ACTIVITIES,
     USERS
WHERE USERS.ID = ACTIVITIES.USR_ID;
```

### ENTITIES

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "USERS")
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "USERS_ID", sequenceName = "USERS_ID")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USERS_ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CNAME", nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String cname;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Immutable
@Table(name = "V_LOGS")
public class LogsView {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USR_ID", nullable = false)
    private long usrId;

    @Column(name = "PRT_ID", nullable = false)
    private long prtId;

    @Column(name = "DOC_ID")
    private Long docId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USR_ID",
            nullable = false,
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRT_ID",
            nullable = false,
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private User partner;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOC_ID",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private Document document;

    //others, removed for brevity
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "DOCUMENTS")
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "DOCUMENTS_ID", sequenceName = "DOCUMENTS_ID")
public class Document {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DOCUMENTS_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 1024)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DOC_SIZE", nullable = false)
    private long size;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATED", nullable = false)
    private Date created;

    //others, removed for brevity
}
```

### SPECIFICATION

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogsSpecification implements Specification<LogsView> {
    private final List<SimpleFilter> filters;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<LogsView> root,
                                 CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery,
                                 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(filters)) return null;

        Predicate[] predicates = filters.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(filter -> getPredicate(filter, root, criteriaBuilder))
                .toArray(Predicate[]::new);

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates);
    }

    private Predicate getPredicate(SimpleFilter filter,
                                   Root<LogsView> root,
                                   CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(filter.getName());
        Predicate predicate;
        String[] keys = filter.getName().split("\\.");
        if (filter.getPredicate() == LIKE) {
            predicate = builder.like(
                    builder.upper(PredicateUtils.getChildPath(root, keys)),
                    ("%" + filter.getValue() + "%").toUpperCase());
        } else {
            predicate = builder.equal(
                    PredicateUtils.getChildPath(root, keys),
                    filter.getValue());
        }
        //others, removed for brevity

        return predicate;
    }
}
```

#### REPOSITORY

```java
@Repository
public interface LogsRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<LogsView, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Logs> {}
```

#### SERVICE

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogsService {
    private final LogsRepository logsRepository;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

    public Page<LogsDto> paginated(String name, String value) {
        var type = isNumeric(value) ? SimpleFilter.PredicateType.EQUAL : SimpleFilter.PredicateType.LIKE;
        var filter = new SimpleFilter(name, value, type);
        return logsRepository
                .findAll(new LogsSpecification(List.of(filter)), Pageable.ofSize(10))
                .map(en -> mapper.convertValue(en, LogsDto.class));
    }


    private boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
        return strNum != null && pattern.matcher(strNum).matches();
    }
}
```

### QUERY GENERATED

```sql
-- Hibernate: 
-- executing 5 JDBC statements;
select *
from (select * -- removed for brevity
      from v_logs v_logs0_
               cross join documents document1_
      where v_logs0_.doc_id = document1_.id
        and (
          upper(document1_.name) like ?
          )
        and (
              v_logs0_.usr_id in (4, 72, 76, 123, 147, 199, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22)
          )
        and v_logs0_.usr_id <> 1
      order by v_logs0_.usr_id asc)
where rownum <= ?
```

###### Without `document.name` filter, page 10

```
1.228738106 seconds
```

###### With `document.name` filter, page 10 and results

```
2.900642325 seconds
```

###### With `document.name` filter, page 10 and no results

```
Without IDX_DOC_NAME_UPPER: 240.123813697 seconds, sqlpus: 8-9 seconds
With IDX_DOC_NAME_UPPER: 110.123813697(not stable), seconds sqlpus: 3-4 seconds
```

#### SQL FIDDLE

##### [View Execution Plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3c15/3/0)

### CONFIGURATION

- **Database**: Oracle 19c
- **Jdk**: 11
- **Ojdbc8**: 21.3.0
- **SpringBoot**: 2.6.4
- **Hibernate**: 5.6.5.Final

I recreated a simple application with the code structure, you can find it at this link: [demo-oracle-slow](https://github.com/burl21/demo-oracle-slow).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**1. LIKE is slow**

 In your implementation, you use `LIKE '%string%'`. It fails index search.

Example of LIKE search:
[image]

Use `LIKE 'string%'` and not `LIKE '%string%'`. If you specify a leading character, Oracle has a better chance of being able to use your upper index to perform the query - this will increase performance.

Another option is to try to create an inverse text index in case your name field consists of several words. See [CTXCAT index documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/ind.htm#CCAPP9024). Please note the table memory space will be increased significantly.

**2. Hibernate is generating cross join**
The second problem that Hibernate is generating `cross join`. It needs to be avoided.

Use [`JoinType.INNER`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#JoinType) in your criteria.

Another solution is to define Entity Graph. [Example](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph).

Comment: Good answer. Could you expand on how to avoid cross joins using JPA?

Comment: I have expanded answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
In fact with `'%string%'` it seems that the index is not used, but I don't understand why _sqlplus_ takes only seconds and the application minutes for the same query.
I changed `@Table("V_LOGS")` to `@Subselect("V_LOGS")` in `LogsView` and the dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`.
Now it takes ~15s with `like 'string%'` while for `like '%string%'` takes ~35s when no rows selected.

Comment: Oracle has caching mechanism. Query is slow during the first-time execution then data will be cached for a certain query. Wait at least 30 min while DB clears caches and then execute query via sql plus. Please ensure that your query does not have  CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Today I launched the query from _sql plus_ and then from the application. _Sql plus_ took 2 seconds, however from application even with the same searches in sequence I do not see great improvements
In this post [cross-join-implicit-inner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240959/hql-implicit-join-in-where-clause-generate-cross-join-instead-of-inner-join) says it should be an implicit inner join, right?